# How do I choose a proper component file from Apache Commons?

Tags: java, apache-commons

I don't understand how should I know which Apache Commons jar's to reference if I want to use some of its components.
For example, if I want to use [ObservableCollection](http://commons.apache.org/dormant/events/apidocs/org/apache/commons/events/observable/ObservableCollection.html), how do I know which jar's to reference to be able to use it.

I downloaded [Collections](http://commons.apache.org/collections/) (I added it to my build path) but this component has only "AbstractCollectionDecorator" class. In the documentation I can see that the actual class lies in the package:

```
org.apache.commons.events.observable.ObservableCollection
```

How should I figure out which package to reference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the package name, e.g. *org.apache.commons.events* remove the *org.apache* part.

The next part is *org.apache.commons*, that means it's the Apache Jakarta Commons project group, which is also an aggregator for multiple projects. So we need yet another fragment for the name to distinguish it:

So you got *org.apache.commons.events* now. The name suggest *commons-events*, because Apache Commons Collections would be *org.apache.commons.collections*

So all you have to do is remove *org.apache*, replace the dot with a slash and you've got the jar filename you need:

```
org.apache.commons.events      -> commons-events.jar
org.apache.commons.collections -> commons-collections.jar
org.apache.commons.io          -> commons-io.jar
org.apache.commons.lang        -> commons-lang.jar
```

etc

Answer (score 1):

Note that the path to the javadoc to ObservableCollection starts with
http://commons.apache.org/dormant.  Hmmm... not a good sign.

> How should I figure out which package to rererence?

From the main `dormant` page:

> If you wish to use any of these components, you must build them yourselves. It is best to assume that these components will not be released in the near future.